# create hash from image contents with PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing

I currently create a hash from an image name but would rather create a hash based on the contents of an image so I can detect duplicate images.  Are their any PHP classes that do this?

My current code is very simple:

```
$image = "image1.jpg"; 
$filehash = md5_file($image );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current code you have is actually calculating the md5 of the file contents.  What you already have does what you want.

Comment: @user1216398, Your assumption was wrong.  If you want to md5 a string (such as a file name) just use `md5()`.

Comment: While this seems to be the desired answer, it would not identify identical images if they were in different formats, or even had one bit of different metadata. Looking around, I came across this project, which actually calculates a similarity index based on the pixel data: http://www.thismayhem.com/php/comparing-images-with-php-gd/

Comment: @pixelistik, that depends on your definition of identical.  If you are trying to de-dupe files, md5 is sufficient.  If you want to break into the actual image data, then yes, you need an alternate method that actually targets image data.

Comment: I think my md5 solution will work for now.  Basically just trying to prevent a user from uploading duplicate images.

Answer (score 3):

As you mention content, you might want to have a look at a perceptual hash, such as [phash](http://www.phash.org/)